# Преобразование Pandas Timestamp в string

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, dataframe

Есть код парсера:

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd
def read_zip(zip_fn, extract_fn=None):
    zf = ZipFile(zip_fn)
    if extract_fn:
        return zf.read(extract_fn)
    else:
        return {name:zf.read(name) for name in zf.namelist()}
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(read_zip(r'C:\download\test.xlsx.zip', 'test.xlsx')))
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
```

Преобразовал в кортеж для того, чтобы записать в БД.

Но `Timestamp` записывает не правильно в БД, из-за этого мне придется преобразовать в `string`.

Comment: а зачем вообще преобразовывать в кортежи? почему сразу не писать из pandas в базу данных?

Comment: @strawdog когда записываю, формат портится полностью, он мешает день, месяц, год. вот код записи (TO_DATE(:1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')

Comment: @user357670, df.to_sql(table_name, sqlalchemy_engine) - пробовали?

Comment: @MaxU все таки решил преобрзовать в string, заметил что datetime тоже не особо подходит.

Comment: @user357670, какой у вас тип данных в SQL таблице? Почему не подходит `datetime64`? По-моему, наиболее правильный вариант - это когда у вас в DataFrame `datetime64` (чтобы проверить посмотрите `df.dtypes`) и в таблице `DATE` или `TIMESTAMP` - тогда Pandas и SQL Alchemy сами сделают правильные преобразования. Хранение даты/времени в строке - не вариант (вернее так можно делать только для SQLite БД, у которой нет встроенного типа `DATE`)

Comment: @MaxU у меня тип данных в таблице DATE в бд. Я в xlrd получал ввиде string затем когда записывал пользовался функцией to_date вот так (TO_DATE(:1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') и у меня все нормально работала, здесь pandas почему то всегда выдает мне timestamp. Хотя я с вами конечно согласен что делаю лишнюю работа.

Comment: какая у вас БД?

Comment: @MaxU DB oracle

Comment: А где в вашем сообщении собственно вопрос? У вас сложности его сформулировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import cx_Oracle
from cx_Oracle import makedsn
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


usr = "test"
pwd = "my_oracle_password"
dsn = makedsn("ora_scan_or_hostname", 1521, service_name="my_service_name")

df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(read_zip(r'C:\download\test.xlsx.zip', 'test.xlsx')), 
                   parse_dates=['your_date_column_name'])

engine = create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://{usr}:{pwd}@{dsn}')

df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append')
```